# factory pattern in autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I want to implement factory pattern in Autofac. This is how it was done in Ninject:

```
Bind<ICarFilter>().To<CarFilter >();
Bind<IBikeFilter>().To<BikeFilter>();
Bind<IFilterFacade>().ToFactory().InSingletonScope();
```

This is a definitnion of IFilterFacade

```
public interface IFilterFacade
    {    
        ICarFilter CreateCarFilter();

        IBikeFIlter CreateBikeFilter();         
    }
```

If I want an instance of CarFilter type, all I need to do is the following:

```
public class HomeController(IFilterFacade filterFacade)
{
    FilterFacade = filterFacade;
}

public IFilterFacade FilterFacade { get;set; }

public ActionResult Index()
{
  var bikeFilter = FilterFacade.CreateBikeFilter();
}
```

Any example how to do that in AutoFac. I checked AutoFac documentation, but was not able to find the answer or example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ninject (bit I am with Autofac), can you please explain the behavior you had with Ninject? Did Ninject dynamically implement the IFilterFacade interface for you? Or did you implement it by yourself?

Comment: @felix-b yeah, it is dynamically implemented by Ninject.

Comment: Autofac has no such feature, AFAIK. With Autofac, you can receive IComponentContext in constructor of your controller. You can then resolve individual components from that IComponentContext, e.g. context.Resolve<IBikeFilter>() . Compared to this approach, why using facade interface is important to you?

Comment: All I want is to get a concrete implementation of the IBikeFilter in my Index method, not within the constructor.

>why using facade interface is important to you.

Because there is another method in HomeController that should create implementation of the ICarFilter. I don't like the idea of passing filter multiple dependencies through controller because sometimes in the future, there might be much more fliters.

Comment: Aggregate services may help you here.

Answer (score 9):

There is no equivalent of `ToFactory` in *Autofac* but you can easily implement a generic factory equivalent.

```
public interface IFilterFactory
{
    TFilter Get() where TFilter : IFilter; 
}

public class FilterFactory : IFilterFactory
{

    public FilterFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this._scope = scope; 
    }

    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope; 

    public TFilter Get<TFilter>()
    {
        return this._scope.Resolve<TFilter>(); 
    }
}
```

Then register it like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<FilterFactory>().As<IFilterFactory>(); 
builder.RegisterType<BikeFilter>().As<IBikeFilter>(); 
builder.RegisterType<CarFilter>().As<ICarFilter>();
```

and use it this way

```
public class HomeController
{ 
    private readonly IFilterFactory _filters;

    public HomeController(IFilterFactory filters)
    {
        this._filters = filters; 
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var bikeFilter = this._filters.Get<IBikeFilter>();
        // ...
    }
}
```

I rename the `Create` method to `Get` because the method will look up an instance in the lifetime scope and create one only if needed.

Another possible solution may be to use [Named and Keyed Service](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) and the built-in `IIndex` type.

```
builder.RegisterType<BikeFilter>().Named<IFilter>("Bike"); 
builder.RegisterType<CarFilter>().Named<IFilter>("Car");
```

then on your controller

```
public class HomeController
{ 
    private readonly IIndex<String, IFilter> _filters;

    public HomeController(IIndex<String, IFilter> filters)
    {
        this._filters = filters; 
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var bikeFilter = this._filters["Bike"];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a NuGet which does exactly this but over `IServiceCollection`.

https://github.com/czmirek/AddFactoryExtension

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AddFactoryExtension

Answer (score 0):

Autofac has no such feature as dynamically implementing user-defined factory interface. It does allow binding to delegates, but it's not the same.

If you want to receive a kind of factory in constructor, then obtain individual components from that factory in relevant methods, it is definitely possible with Autofac.

**Composition root**

Here I register individual components as singletons (this was the behavior with Ninject, if I get it correctly), but you can use any lifetime option that fits your requirements.

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<BikeFilter>().As<IBikeFilter>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<CarFilter>().As<ICarFilter>().SingleInstance();
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController
{ 
    private readonly IComponentContext _components;

    public HomeController(IComponentContext components)
    {
        _components = components; // instead of factory interface
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var bikeFilter = _components.Resolve<IBikeFilter>();
        // ...
    }
}
```

**BTW**

I think that factory interface is a nice feature of Ninject. Another added value of it is allowing to explore through IntelliSense. In your example, when I type `FilterFacade` and the dot character, I'm presented with a list of supported filters (CreateCarFilter, CreateBikeFilter, ...). So that even if I'm not fully familiar with the project codebase, I can pick one that fits best. With Autofac, `IComponentContext` allows me request **any** component, which doesn't help me find out what relevant components exist, or which components I'm expected to request.